# How to create a profile url in nodejs like facebook?

Tags: node.js, express

i want to create a profile URL in my NodeJs project like facebook

Example: http://localhost:3000/anehkumar

I try a lot but have no luck so please help me. I am using express in this.

Thank you.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define dynamicly params in router like below;

```
app.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
   // make somethings with username
   var username = req.params.username;
})
```

Comment: Hi, i try your code it work but know i have new issue now when ever i try to open other page like http://localhost:3000/about or other http://localhost:3000/user/profile it open same page which i use for username.

Comment: if you define /about /other or etc routes before this route defining thats will be work.